# How to determine wether a post gets just created

Tags: metabox

when showing a post of a custom posttype with my metabox, I would like to check, if this is the first,instantiating call for this post.

Is there a WP-function or elegant way to do this?

Comment: when your are on the "new" page, you have `post_status` = `auto-draft`

Comment: @Kaperto: Thanks, that's it. Would you make it an answer, so I can accept it? Regards, ejoo